# XlsxWriter override Bar-Line Chart

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to create a Bar-Line Chart in Python using XlsxWriter.

Excel has an option to this but this module doesn't seem to.
Any possible to override the xlsxwriter module.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.6.8 of XlsxWriter, it is possible to [create combined charts](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_charts.html#chart-combined-charts).